# Can Panel Handle Hot Tub - 50 amps

Tags: electrical-panel, hot-tub

I am looking at purchasing a hot tub that requires 230v/50amp and I was wondering if my panel could handle it? Any help is much appreciate, image below..

[image: panel]

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of the panel's door please?

Comment: Ah, the 8-penny nail handle tie. A classic. But a classic that should be replaced with a proper handle tie...

Comment: Looks probably ok, particularly since it looks like a 240v load was removed from an old furnace. The old furnace probably had some electric heat, if it was gas it likely would have been a single pole for a 120v motor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two open slots at the top right-hand side of the breakers looks from the photos as though it can handle a double breaker needed for 230V.

So from what you've shown the answer appears to be yes.